# Как добавить в список значения по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я новичок в js подскажите пожалста, как решить такое
У меня есть следующая структура

```
<a>link</a>
<ul class="r">
    <li>
        <div class="name">A789</div>
        <div class="id">7</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="name">B7</div>
        <div class="id">87</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо по клику по ссылке получать значения name, id и добавлять их в список.
Пример ниже

```
window.dataR = window.dataR || [];
dataR.push({
    "eco": {
        "purchase": {
            "actionField": {
                "id" : 1
            },
            "products": [
                {
                    "id": "A789",
                    "name" : "7",
                },
                {
                    "id": "B7",
                    "name" : "87",
                }
            ]
        }
    } 
});
```

Для этого пишу, но ничего не выходит

```
 $(document).on("click", "a", function(){
        $.each($("ul.r"), function(i,e)){
            dataR.push.eco.products($(e).find("name"))
            dataR.push.eco.products($(e).find("id"))
        }
    })
```

Comment: "Пример ниже" - пример чего? Что такое `dataR`? В какой список (массив?) должны добавляться данные - в `dataR` или в `dataR[0].eco.products`? Данные надо собирать со всех `ul` на странице? Они все содержат элементы одинаковой структуры?

Comment: мне необходимо добавлять данные из ul с классом r в объект dataR поле products

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dataR = [];
dataR.push({
  "eco": {
    "purchase": {
      "actionField": {
        "id" : 1
      },
      "products": [
      ]
    }
  } 
});

$(document).on("click", "a", function(){
  $("ul.r li .id").each(function(index){
    var _id = $(this).text();
    var _name = $(this).closest("li").find(".name").text();
    dataR[0].eco.purchase.products.push({ "id": _id, "name": _name });
  });
  console.log(dataR);
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>link</a>
<ul class="r">
    <li>
        <div class="name">A789</div>
        <div class="id">7</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="name">B7</div>
        <div class="id">87</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо теперь я разобрался

Comment: @bot галочка слева - щёлк :)